Flutter Future<List<Image>> convert to List<Image>
List<Image> convertToImgList(Future<List<Image>> listimg) {
  var li = listimg.asStream();
  Future<int> future = listimg.asStream().length;
  return images;
}

Hi,
I want to convert Future List Image to List Image in flutter.
Anyone knows how it can be done?

It is future so you much wait for it by await:
void main () async {
  Future<List<Image>> listimg = _yourFutureData();
  List<Image> imageList = await listimg;
}

Example with FutureBuilder:
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Image>>(
      future: plitImage('assets/images/filmdirector.png'),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data == null) {
          return const SizedBox();
        }

        final List<Image> imageList = snapshot.data;

        // You can use imageList here to return your Widget;
      },
    );
  }
}


Okay, but how do i access each image from this imageList ?

You can check my edited answer with FutureBuilder which can use to build widget with Future data @ADR

Convert from Future<List<Image>>
final Future<List<Image>> listFutureImages = Future<List<Image>>();
final List<Image> listImages = await listFutureImages;

Convert from List<Future<Image>>
final Future<List<Image>> listFutureImages = List<Future<Image>>();
final List<Image> listImages = await  Future.wait(
   listFutureImages.map(
      (e) async => await e,
   ),
);


But if we await, then that function needs to be async, and async function's return type should be Future<List.
This is where i am stuck.

I understand what you mean. But this is impossible. Why do you have to do that?

void main() {
runApp(const MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({super.key});
// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
title: 'IchooseApp',
theme: ThemeData(
primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
),
home: const MyHomePage(),
);
}
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
const MyHomePage({
super.key,
});
@override
State createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Future<List> tilelist;
final Future<List> listImages =
splitImage('assets/images/filmdirector.png');
tilelist = _buildGridTileList(9, listImages.then((value) => null));
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Image'),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[


const SizedBox(
height: 16,
),
GridView.builder(
gridDelegate: gridDelegate, itemBuilder: itemBuilder),
GridView.extent(
maxCrossAxisExtent: 150,
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
mainAxisSpacing: 4,
crossAxisSpacing: 4,
children: tilelist),
],
),
),
// This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
);
}
}

can i get your mail id,,,so to share the code

Please use FutureBuilder.
See example:
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    super.key,
  });
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Future<List<ListTile>> tilelist;
    // final Future<List<Image>> listImages =
    //     splitImage('assets/images/filmdirector.png');
    // tilelist = _buildGridTileList(9, listImages.then((value) => null));
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _yourFutureImage(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final image = snapshot.data as List<String>;
          return Scaffold();
        });
  }

  _yourFutureImage() async {
    return [''];
  }
}


